# SourceTree on Windows with OpenSSH

Tags: windows, github, atlassian-sourcetree, openssh

Running Windows 7, SourceTree 1.5.1.0 configured to use openssh, running against GitHub.

When my private key (stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh`) is called `id_rsa` everything works fine: I can clone github repositories, pull, etc. But when I rename my private key to something else (and let SourceTree know about this, of course), it fails to connect.

Furthermore: if I create `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\config` and add something like

```
Host github2
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile something_else
```

it still doesn't work. As if the OpenSSH in SourceTree is hardwired to read only `id_rsa`.

Ideas?

Comment: What do you see in `Tools > Options > General > SSH Client Configuration` ?

Comment: @LoicAG: "SSH Key" is set to the correct file; "SSH Client" is set to "OpenSSH"; and the "automatically start SSH agent" is checked (though disabled. When SourceTree starts is pops up the text console saying "loading SSH key into agent for authentication", though the agent icon does *not* appear in the system tray (should it, in OpenSSH? My keys are not password protected).

Comment: The only system tray icon that I'm aware of is Pageant.  OpenSSH does have a windows service, but it doesn't have a system tray icon.